# How to set azure logic app definition using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to set the definition of the logic app using powershell, this is the line I'm using:

```
Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "dummy-dev-rg" -ResourceName "dummy-la-d" -Definition "{\"definition\":{\"$schema\":\"https:\/\/schema.management.azure.com\/providers\/Microsoft.Logic\/schemas\/2016-06-01\/workflowdefinition.json#\",\"actions\":{},\"contentVersion\":\"1.0.0.0\",\"outputs\":{},\"parameters\":{},\"triggers\":{}},\"parameters\":{}}"
```

I took the definition from the logic app itself and converted it to JSON using an online tool, I'm getting this result:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'definition\:{\\:\https:\/\/schema.management.azure.com\/providers\/Microsoft.Logic\/schemas\/2016-06-01\/workfl
    owdefinition.json#\,\actions\:{},\contentVersion\:\1.0.0.0\,\outputs\:{},\parameters\:{},\triggers\:{}},\parameters\:{}}'.
    At line:1 char:1
```

I'm assuming the definition format is wrong, how can I pass a correct one?

Comment: You just need to escape your string properly. You get an error because you use double quotes to surround a string containing also double quotes. You need to escape all double-quotes within the string by placing a backtick in front of them or doubling all the double quotes that are part of the string. 

Alternatively, in your case, the simplest option is to drop those surrounding double quotes and use single quotes instead so no escaping is needed.

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the commands below.

```
$json = '{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
"actions": {},
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"outputs": {},
"parameters": {},
"triggers": {}
}'

Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName xxxx -ResourceName joylogic -Definition $json
```

[image]

And you should note the last `parameters` in your command belongs to `-Parameters` parameter, you need to use it instead of `-Definition`.