# Azure Logic App not updated in destination Resource Group (PowerShell)

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I am trying to deploy an existing Logic App from a source Resource Group to a destination Resource Group via PowerShell:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <DestinationResourceGroup> -TemplateFile <TemplateFile>  -TemplateParameterFile <ParametersFile>
```

The deployment is "sucessful" but the destination LogicApp is not getting updated

Is there any way to update the Logic App in the destination Resource Group? Do I have to delete and create it again every time?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few workarounds that you can try

**WAY-1**
To use [Set-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/set-azlogicapp?view=azps-7.3.2) which modifies a logic app in a resource group.

```
Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName <YOURRESOURCEGROUP> -Name <YOURLOGICAPP> -DefinitionFilePath <PATHOFYOURDEFINITIONFILE> -ParameterFilePath <PATHOFYOURPARAMETERFILE>
```

**WAY-2**
You can store the ARM template in a variable and use in `Set-AzLogicApp`

```
$json = '{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
"actions": {},
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"outputs": {},
"parameters": {},
"triggers": {}
}'

Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName <YOURRESOURCEGROUPNAME> -ResourceName <YOURLOGICAPPNAME> -Definition $json
```

**WAY-3**
Just copy and paste your code view everytime after successful run.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Set-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/set-azlogicapp?view=azps-7.3.2)
2. [How to set azure logic app definition using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607494/how-to-set-azure-logic-app-definition-using-powershell)

Comment: Thanks! Trying Set-AzLogicApp but getting this error: Set-AzLogicApp: The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'variables' on object of type 'FlowTemplate'. Path 'properties.definition.variables', line 21, position 18.'.